# Getting values from DataDictionary in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine

I am learning Google Earth Engine with no prior knowledge of javascript (coming from R and python). Following the FeatureCollection tutorial with the following script:

```
// Load watersheds from a data table.
var sheds = ee.FeatureCollection('USGS/WBD/2017/HUC06')
  // Filter to the continental US.
  .filterBounds(ee.Geometry.Rectangle(-127.18, 19.39, -62.75, 51.29))
  // Convert 'areasqkm' property from string to number.
  .map(function(feature){
    var num = ee.Number.parse(feature.get('areasqkm'));
    return feature.set('areasqkm', num);
  });

// Display the table and print its first element.
Map.addLayer(sheds, {}, 'watersheds');
print(sheds.limit(1));

// Print the number of watersheds.
print('Count:', sheds.size());

// Print stats for an area property.
print('Area stats:', sheds.aggregate_stats('areasqkm'));
```

The last step creates something that the console calls a DataDictionary. This doesn't seem to behave like a normal dictionary, & I can't figure out how to access the individual elements within. I assigned the results with

`var areaStats = sheds.aggregate_stats('areasqkm')`

And then tried all of the following:

```
print(areaStats.get('mean'));
print(areaStats.mean);
print(areaStats['mean']);
```

Which resulted in the error `areaStats.get is not a function` for the first and simply printing 'undefined' for the others. What is going on? I can clearly see a value called 'mean' if I print `areaStats` in the console.

I might not ever need to use this code on my own data, but it bothers me that I can't figure out something as apparently simple as how to access elements within a dictionary!

Comment: I believe that aggregate_stats() will not allow you to access the stats for use as variables in your code--it's just for inspection in the console. You would instead want to use a Reducer to make a FeatureCollection which you can indeed access. I didn't write an answer because I'm not certain this is correct.

Comment: I agree with @Jon. One thing that can be done is using evaluate or getInfo functions to get the Object to client side which can then be manipulated as standard JS object like a dictionary.

Comment: Yes you're right @Jon, I tried that approach and it does indeed work. I'll post the answer

Answer (score 1):

Here is a workaround for accessing the results from `aggregate_stats()` using the Python API.

```
def summary_statistics(collection, column):

    stats = collection.aggregate_stats(column).getInfo()
    return eval(str(stats)).get('values')

results = summary_statistics(your_collection, column_name)
print(results.get('sum'))
print(results.get('mean'))
```

Answer (score 0):

It does appear that you can't access the results from `aggregate_stats()`, but you can use Reducer to get stats as variables. The code below calculates the mean only, which matches the result from `aggregate_stats` (25513.32264880953):

```
var meanArea = 
  // Calculate mean area across polygons
  sheds.reduceColumns(ee.Reducer.mean(), ['areasqkm'])
  .get('mean');
print('Area mean:', meanArea);
```